# Solr XSLTResponseWriter

Tags: html, xslt, solr, nutch

Am using Nutch and Solr for crawling web. when queried from solr interface, the result is in XML format. i want it to be displayed in normal html output.

I have tried to attach the xslt steelsheet to the response of SOLR with
passing this 2 variables wt=xslt&tr=example.xsl referred from 
 http://grokbase.com/t/nutch/user/103xcghta8/getting-solr-response-in-html-format-htmlresponsewriter

then it works to some expectation but this is a manual input which everytime i have to write when querying.

Can this be done automatically by modifying certain files in solr and nutch?

Answer (score 0):

Add the parameters to the request handler

```
<str name="wt">json</str>
<str name="tr">example.xsl</str>
```

Comment: hi, Jayendra, i added the parameters, but it didnt work..did i place it in wrong reqquest handler? i added it in

Comment: <requestHandler name="/browse" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
<str name="wt">xslt</str>
<str name="tr">example.xsl</str>
       <!-- VelocityResponseWriter settings -->

       <str name="wt">velocity</str>

Comment: Try this. In solrconfig use <requestHandler name="browse" ...> And then, in your Solr query, use the parameter "qt=browse"